# Jquery - Rendering special characters or replacing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a simple page with data tables. If a user inputs characters such as: < > " ' & , they come out as `&lt; &gt; &quot; &#39; &amp;`.

I want to implement a jQuery solution to replace the text `&lt; &gt; &quot; &#39; &amp;` to their proper characters. I have a container table named #reload_me and inside that I have all my data in other sub tables.

I tried the following code as an example but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error `TypeError: $(...).replaceText is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#reload_me").replaceText("&amp;", "&" );
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle?

Comment: This is the closest I could get to recreate my table. https://jsfiddle.net/jxyzwx3e/ I had to remove the & in front of the texts '&lt; &gt; &quot; &#39; &amp;' just to give a more realistic example. Fiddle off course id loading it correctly lol

Comment: Just another comment, just keep in mind that these are tables rendering from SharePoint 2007 so quite possibly there is an escape issue with SharePoint itself but I gave up trying to fix SharePoint and just trying to get a quick and dirty fix to this.

Comment: Example you provided didn't realy exposed the problem but maybe this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/8wtmkaju/

Comment: This is an example of your issue. I will post the solution in a moment, but I was able to reproduce this because the issue is as I described in my post: https://jsfiddle.net/jxyzwx3e/1/

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that this is plugin functionality that is not part of jQuery core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where `.replaceText` came from, but those values that you are seeing are the ASCII values for the characters. If your characters are currently displaying with their ASCII representations visible, then that means that the text displaying the ASCII values is TEXT and not HTML, since HTML would render the desired representation of the character. As such, replacing the target element's contents using jQuery's `.html` method should cause the characters to display correctly:

```
var $reloadMe = $("#reload_me");
$reloadMe.html($reloadMe.text());
```

Here is the full working sample:

```js
var sample = "data data data &lt; &gt; &quot; &#39; &amp;";

var $td = $("td");
$td.text(sample);

$("#btnFixIt").on("click", function() {
    $td.each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.html($this.text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>1st record table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>2nd record table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>3rd record table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="btnFixIt">Fix it</button>
```

Comment: I gave this a try but didn't make any difference.

Comment: I had a typo - it should have been `$reloadMe.text()` inside the parenthesis

Comment: Hi Zachary, if I try running the following code `$("td").each(function() {var $this = $(this); $this.html($this.text());});` it removes all my tables and just leaves me with a block of text however it does convert the the characters correctly. I tried doing `$("#reload_me td")` but results are the same.

Comment: Scratch that I was able to add classes to the TD with data and target those only and using CSS I added white-space: pre-wrap and that kept my line breaks correctly. THis issue can now be considered as closed. Thank you again Zachary

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem seem to be with the next quote

> Note: If a < div> , < span> , or < noembed> node has a child text node that includes the characters (&), (<), or (>), innerHTML returns these characters as &amp, &lt and &gt respectively. Use element.textContent to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: That is expected behavior because `.innerHTML` returns markup that can be reapplied to an element or re-inserted into the DOM. The reason why those characters have special representations that must be used in markup is because if their actual representations were used it could cause issues in parsing. They are essentially escape characters.

Comment: Also, the OP never mentions the use of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my issue by following this guide http://logicflowau.blogspot.ca/2009/08/sharepoint-xslt-data-view-issues_1789.html. This is a Sahrepoint fix rather than a Jquery fix.

```
Add this function to your DispForm.aspx file:

    <xsl:template name="formatMultiLineText">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#xa;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&#xa;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:call-template name="formatMultiLineText">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#xa;')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


Where your multiple line text is displaying, replace this:

    <xsl:value-of select="@Description">


with this:

    <xsl:call-template name="formatMultiLineText">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Description">
    </xsl:call-template>
```